# how to config SlickUpload 6 AJAX to NOT require a file

Tags: asp.net, configuration, slickupload

I've been trying to figure out how to make the current SlickUpload 6.1.7 play nice in a form that does not require someone to include files. We want it to be optional. This form is for people to contact us, and we want to give them the option to include attachments, just not require it. It works if you upload a file, however the form will not submit, if you do not upload any file.

We are trying to use the Ajax version with Memory stream, but the 'AspNetAjaxCs-VS2010' sample code is not helping much...  the documentation is sparse, and the samples have little constancy between them, making it hard to understand how exactly it all works. (at least for me) The fact that they got bought out, and the new owner company pretty much ignores people unless they are paying for it, is not cool.

Any ideas?

Comment: to refine my question. How do we make SlickUpload 6.1.7 accept ZERO files uploaded as valid, so it will not block the rest of the from from submitting?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a div to detect a drop inside your page. That way you could only activate it when the user really need it, or whenever the using actually select something for uploading, like a trigger.

Comment: i'm sorry I don't follow... I want Slick to validate with zero files uploaded, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if so, it sounds like you already have a form that you want to use SlickUpload with to upload files *IF* there are files to be uploaded.  Are you using the CustomUploadStreamProvider form?

Comment: we are using the uploadStreamProvider type memory.

Comment: how can I refine my question to help? (every page on my site is a webform because of ASP.NET?)  On the pages in question I want to be able to submit an a form you can fill in, yet if slick has not uploaded any files, it will not do anything.  it seems slick REQUIRES at least 1 file to be valid.  I can't figure out how to tell it it's ok if there are zero files attached....